Condition for complex roots of quartic to be concyclic
Given a general quartic
$$
az^4+bz^3+cz^2+dz+e=0
$$
with complex coefficients, I am curious about whether we can impose a relation on the coefficients equivalent to the concyclicity of the four roots $\{z_i\}$.
I know that the four roots are concyclic iff their cross ratio
$$
\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}
$$
is real, including the colinear case. However, I failed to convert this into equations that coefficients should satisfy.

Do my desired equalities exist, or perhaps I need something else like inequalities?

The question arises out of my curiosity, so it may not have a good solution.
Thanks in advance.

What about this nice article by T. E. McKinney from 1907: "Condition in Terms of the Invariants of the Quartic that its Four Distinct Root-Points be Concyclic": jstor.org/stable/2970799 . You may also want  to have a look at  "MATHEMATICAL NOTES" by T. TAKAGI, Tokyo Sugaku-Butsurigakkwai Hokoku 1903 Volume 2 Issue 6 Pages 25-29,
https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/subutsuhokoku1901/2/6/2_6_25/_article

If you are interested in something beautiful: the cubic equation was solved by Tartaglia in 1539, but is most often attributed to Cardano (1545). Tartaglia communicated the result to Cardano in a poem (!). See here (Italian original, rhyming): https://old.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/how-tartaglia-solved-the-cubic-equation-tartaglias-original-poem or here (English translation, prose): https://old.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/how-tartaglia-solved-the-cubic-equation-tartaglias-poem . So people answering this question may feel invited to give their answer in rhymes ...

@Andreas Thanks for your reference. I cannot quite get Takagi's method, so maybe you can post an answer.
